# Using the citation ontology in HTML pages

Tags: html, xml, metadata, rdf

CiTO, the Citation Typing Ontology, is an ontology for describing the nature of reference citations in scientific research articles and other scholarly works, both to other such publications and also to Web information resources, and for publishing these descriptions on the Semantic Web, [as described in this paper (open access)](http://www.jbiomedsem.com/content/1/S1/S6)

Though the paper does an excellent job explaining the terms available in the ontology, I have only an elementary knowledge of XML, HTML, and RDF and I'm a bit unclear how to go about implementing this in a webpage.

Let us imagine that I am writing a blog post online and which to indicate that the line I have just written refutes the citation that follows it.  Would I just write:

```
... refutes the analysis of <a rel="cito:refutes" href="http://dx.doi/org/10.1126/science.1197258">Wolfe et al. 2010</a>.
```

Or do I need to specify the namespace for CiTO somewhere?

e.g. do I need to format the page as XML, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html xmlns="http://purl.org/net/cito/">
```

Is the line `<html xmlns="http://purl.org/net/cito/">` the correct way to add a namespace?

In constructing the link, obviously there are many URLs that I could give for the same paper.  Is there any best practice on how to choose these, or additional attribute I can set to pass the doi explicitly?  Or do I need to point to a URL that has cito data embedded?  How does this relate to the use of the "rev" tag in html anchors, and is there any time I would add the cito link in the `rev` tag?

Once I have done this, is there an obvious programmatic way to generate RDF file containing my citations with their CiTO meanings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like using RDFa attributes, rather then `rel` or `rev` tags, would be the most effective way to do this.

The following solution is adapted from scholarlyhtml.org, after adding DOCTYPE, mime-type, and changing the `rel` attributes of the links into the RDFa `property` attributes, and the `resource` attributes on links to `href`, after which it successfully validates on the W3C HTML5 nu [validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" property="http://scholarly-html.org/schtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Scholarly HTML </title>
</head>
<body>

    <span property="http://purl.org/dc/terms/title">Title</span>
    <span property="http://purl.org/dc/terms/creator">Author</span>

    <p>Some text which then refers to a cited work
          <a   property="http://purl.org/spar/cito/obtainsBackgroundFrom"  href="http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/B411699M">[citation]</a>
          but it would still be valid if the citation had been formatted and something along the
          lines of
          <a   property="http://purl.org/spar/cito/obtainsBackgroundFrom" href="http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/B411699M">Adams, 2007</a> is also
          allowable.
    </p>
    <p>References can also involve explicitly declaring the elements of the reference entry.
          So the following is also allowable.
          <a property="http://purl.org/spar/cito/parodies" href="#citation">[citation]</a> In this case the information needs to be
          provided elsewhere in the document, possibly in a separate div for the reference list
          entries such as below.
    </p>

<div id="biblography" property="http://purl.org/spar/biro/ReferenceList">
  <span id="citation" property="http://purl.org/spar/biro/BibliographicRecord" about="http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/B411699M">
    <span property="http://purl.org/dc/terms/title">
      Experimental data checker: better information for organic chemists</span>
    <span property="http://purl.org/dc/terms/creator">
        <span resource="http://people.cam.ac.uk/sea36">
            <span property="http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/name" content="Samuel E. Adams">S. E. Adams</span>
        </span>,
        <span resource="http://people.cam.ac.uk/jmg">
            <span property="http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/name">J. M. Goodman</span>
        </span>,
    </span>
    <span property="http://purl.org/dc/terms/isPartOf" resource="[http://purl.org/dc/terms/journal]">
        <span property="http://purl.org/dc/terms/title" content="Organic &amp; Biomolecular Chemistry">
        </span>
        <span property="http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/shortTitle">Org. Biomol. Chem.</span>
    </span>
    <span property="http://purl.org/dc/terms/date">2004</span>,
    <span property="http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/volume">2</span>
    (<span property="http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/issue">21</span>),
    <span property="http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/pageStart">3067</span>-
    <span property="http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/pageEnd">3070</span>            <br/>
        DOI: <a href="http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/B411699M" property="http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/doi">10.1039/B411699M</a>
  </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd be curious to hear any recommendations for how this could be improved, and also whether this could be implemented in microdata instead.